# Сортировка HashMap строковое значение

Tags: java

Суть задания такая, из консоли(в моем случае powershell) взять среднее значение ping любого сервера. Все сделал, взял, занес в переменные. Но нужно вывести в порядке убывания среднего времени отклика, как это можно сделать?

```
public class lab1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Введите 3 IP адреса: ");
    ArrayList<String> ip = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> averageTime = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String,String> ipAndAverageTime = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ip.add(scr.nextLine());
        averageTime.add(getAverageTime(ip.get(i)));
        ipAndAverageTime.put(ip.get(i), averageTime.get(i));
    }

}

public static String getAverageTime(String ip) throws IOException {
    String command = String.format("ping %s | ForEach-Object {if($_ -match 'Average = (\\d+)'){$Matches[1]}}", ip);
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "powershell.exe", "/c", command);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String averageTime;
    averageTime = r.readLine();
    if(averageTime == null) {
        System.out.println("Не правильный IP адрес");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return averageTime;
}
```

Comment: "сделал, взял", "Марьяна" - ??

Comment: Сложить всё время отклика и разделить на количество? Пока непонятно какие у вас данные и какой ожидаемый результат. Например, у вас данные уже есть и это в `ipAndAverageTime`, теперь вам нужно его обработать, но вы не знаете как, поэтому вам нужно привести пример `ipAndAverageTime`

Comment: Добавил полный исходный код(к ответу выше, аккаунт девушки)

Comment: Нет, я уже взял из консоли конкретное среднее время, в хешмапу занес данные: ключ - ip, введенный пользователем, значение среднее время в строке. Необходимо вывести все что есть в хешмапе в порядке убывания

Comment: А почему у вас время отклика в виде строки, если сравнивать в лексикографическом порядке, то "6" > "10"?

Comment: Потому что беру данные из консоли. То есть желательно изначально парсить строку в int, а затем уже в хешмапу добавлять?

Comment: Если ответ будет целочисленный - можно `int`,- имеет смысл привести образец хешмапы.

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода содержимого хешмапы в отсортированном порядке можно воспользоваться методом `Stream::sorted`, где поток данных будет получен из множества элементов этой хешмапы `entrySet`:

```java
Map<String, String> ipResponse = Map.of(
    "127.0.0.1", "1",
    "8.8.8.8", "15",
    "194.38.168.170", "135"
);


// сортировка по численному значению 135 > 15 > 1
ipResponse.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, String>comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt)).reversed())
    .forEach(System.out::println);

194.38.168.170=135
8.8.8.8=15
127.0.0.1=1
```

```
// сортировка в обратном лексикографическом порядке "15" > "135" > "1"
ipResponse.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
    .forEach(System.out::println);

8.8.8.8=15
194.38.168.170=135
127.0.0.1=1
```

---

Или же можно создать сортированное множество `SortedSet` с требуемым компаратором, добавить в него содержимое мапы, и вывести:

```java
SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, String>> sorted = new TreeSet<>(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()));
sorted.addAll(ipResponse.entrySet());
sorted.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Сделал как вы предложили, но отдельным методом. Метод имеет возвращаемое значение void, и без цикла forEach. Почему при вызове метода sortAverageTime(ipAndAverageTime); и последующим System.out.printl выводит не отсортированный массив?

Comment: Потому что все изменения остаются внутри этого метода, если вы ничего не передаёте наружу.  `ipAndAverageTime` у вас объявлена как обычная хэшмапа, которая по определению не является сортированной и не гарантирует никакого порядка сортировки.

Comment: А передать по ссылке, как в том же с++ возможно?

Comment: Просто вывод должен быть немного другой, c указанием ms

Comment: Просто вывод должен быть немного другой, c указанием ms. То есть как сейчас, но с ms 1.1.1.1 = 47ms... С конструкцией forEach(System.out::println) встречаюсь в первые, и не могу найти информацию как она работает, перебрасывает на System.out.println

Comment: Исправил, заменил на лямда выражение(хотя это таким и было).

Comment: _А передать по ссылке, как в том же с++ возможно?_  Нет, в Джаве в данном случае так нельзя сделать.   Если бы в метод передавалась ссылка на массив/список неких объектов (контейнер, поддерживающий порядок), то его можно было бы отсортировать внутри метода и эти изменения были бы видны снаружи.

Comment: Начал изучать Джаву относительно недавно. То есть как я понял, в Джаве все работает только с локальными копиями, и если хотим как то изменить значение переменной, то необходим метод, возвращающий новое значение?

Comment: @Марьяна, если ответ был полезен, можете отметить его зеленой галочкой и/или проголосовать за него.